# ColdFusion URL array param retrieval

Tags: url, parameters, coldfusion

How do I retrieve array parameters from the URL?
I've passed a JS object through $.getJson and I can see on the server that the dump of URL struct is [image: CFDUMP of URL struct]

This is my testing server side code.

```
<cfdump var="#URL#">
<cfdump var="#URL.nolayout#">
<cfdump var="#URL.user#">
```

However URL.user doesn't exist? How can I retrieve it?

FYI the query string passed is;    `nolayout=true&user%5Badmin_approved%5D=true&user%5Bfully_registered%5D=true&user%5Bfirst_name%5D=Ian&user%5Bid%5D=1&user%5Blogged_in%5D=true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those aren't valid CF variable names so you'll have to use array notation:

```
<cfoutput>#url['user[fully_registered]']#</cfoutput>
```

Yes, it is ugly but it should work.

Comment: @IanOSullivan Shouldn't you pass properly serialized json for user in the query?